# How To Loop Json With Div Element In Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to loop on `<div id="product">` but not count not work well and i want to change example data fakeModel with json for more details here is [preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wbhq8zG6jat2lEPf7Hwb?p=preview), might be able to help me,,

```
fakeModel = {

  id: 1,

  title: 'product',

  description: 'description',

  price: 10,

  tax: 0,

  vendorFees: 0,

  qty: 0

};
```

Comment: I see you have your data in a json file. Get it using `$http.get` and use `ng-repeat` to iterate through it

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fDc5ZE0mwqoaIZfowxgA?p=preview) I've hardcoded the `products.json` in the controller to demonstrate ng-repeat.

Comment: ng-repeat is work. But It's same like me do, it's cannot different between id 1, 2, 3 to increase or decrease cart

Comment: Pass the index of the current product to your function. From there get the price of the `products[index].price` and increment the price

Comment: I want Quantity: {{product [index] .qty}}, like this?

Comment: You pass `$index` to your function. From there you can access any property (price, qty...)

Comment: can you give me some clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate through a list in angular you can try something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div>{{product.title}}</div>
    <div>{{product.price}}</div>
</div>
```

giving IDs to the added divs

```
<div id="product_{{product.id}}" ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div>{{product.title}}</div>
    <div>{{product.price}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give me an example and how can product in products work?

Comment: yeah, now I know ng-repeat, but could not distinguish between the id 1, 2, 3 to increase or decrease cart

Comment: [using 'product_' + product.id as id](http://plnkr.co/edit/13BoagVBkK9G27IHQu74?p=preview)

Comment: where i put this code? 'product' + product.id as id

Comment: Ohh... now I understand the question. Here's a [new](http://plnkr.co/edit/13BoagVBkK9G27IHQu74?p=preview) version.

Comment: [calculating the cart price](http://plnkr.co/edit/13BoagVBkK9G27IHQu74?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">      

        <div ng-repeat="product in fakeModel">
            <div>Product name : {{product.title}}</div>
            <div>Product price : {{product.price}}</div>
        </div>  
    </div>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.fakeModel = [{
                      id: 1,
                      title: 'product',
                      description: 'description',
                      price: 10,
                      tax: 0,
                      vendorFees: 0,
                      qty: 0
                    },
                    {
                      id: 2,
                      title: 'product 2',
                      description: 'description',
                      price: 15,
                      tax: 0,
                      vendorFees: 0,
                      qty: 0
                    }];
            });
      </script>
```

Comment: can i to distinguish between the id 1, 2, 3 to increase or decrease cart in my example?

Comment: Yes, you distinguish id.